# How to transfer data from one table to another 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using sql-server 2008.

I have 3 tables:

```
Item
  - Id
  - Name

ItemLink
  - Id
  - FkParentItemId
  - FkChildItemId

Item2
  - Id
  - FkItemId
  - Name
```

Relationships are:

```
ItemLink >- Item -< item2
         >-
```

I now realise I have made a mistake and need to transfer data from "Item2" to "Item", but create  the hierarchy via inserting an ItemLink record. I do not wish to start a debate on the pros and cons of this approach, but just to add that there are common tables off "Item" that I need for "Item2"

So I need a heads up on the insert ddl required to do this please. I believe it would be something along the lines of:

```
Insert into Item(Name) select(Item2.Name) from Item2
Insert into ItemLink(FkParentItemId,FkChildItemId) select (Item2.FkItemId, New ItemId ??)
```

Bit rusty on this, hence the need for help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to run the code you think should work?

Comment: Is item the table FkChildItemId will come from? This is unclear to me.

Comment: No, it is only pseudo code. My current best idea is to insert into Item, then run an insert from Item to ItemLink. However I am sure there is a more eloquent T-SQL approach. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes FkChildItemId and FKParentItemId are FKs to Item Ids, thereby linking 2 Item records. One is the parent and the other the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I am making some assumptions here.

I assume values in table Item2 are going to stay.

```
 insert into item (name)
 select Name from item2
```

This middle part is unclear to me.
Somehow you will need to update the Fk to Item table.

```
 update item2
 set FkItemId = id
 from item2 inner join item 
 on item.name = item2.name
```

Populate ItemLink

```
 insert into ItemLink ( PkParent, PkChild)
 select item.id, item2.id
 from item2 inner join item 
 on item.id = item2.FkItemId
```

Comment: OK, Thanks. Greatly appreciated for the heads up.